# Android Lost ArrayList Data

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that stores the paths of some images:

```
Map<String, Criterio> irregularidades = CriteriosAdapter.irregularidades;
for(Criterio c : irregularidades.values()) {
    ArrayList<String> listFotos = c.getFotosList();
}
```

However, if the application goes on background by the phone lock, or by some call. When, I try to save the data, I received a null pointer exception.

Could someone help me with that?

**EDIT**

I will add the full code for be easy to understand.

```
public class SaveFragment extends Fragment {

Map<String, String> detailsLoja = LojaDetailsActivity.detailsVistoria;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sync_import, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    saveData();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public void saveData() {

    IrregularidadesDbAdapter mDb;
    mDb = new IrregularidadesDbAdapter(getContext());

    mDb.open();

    int idVistoria = mDb.vistoriaInsert(detailsLoja.get("idBombeiro"), detailsLoja.get("idLoja"), detailsLoja.get("idArea"), changeDate(detailsLoja.get("vistoriaData")));

    Map<String, Criterio> irregularidades = CriteriosAdapter.irregularidades;
    for(Criterio c : irregularidades.values()) {
        int idCriterio = c.getId();
        int idEquipamento = c.getEquipamento();
        int idArea = c.getSubArea;
        ArrayList<String> listFotos = c.getFotosList();

            int idIrregularidade = mDb.insert(idVistoria, idCriterio, idEquipamento, idArea);

            for (int i = 0; i < listFotos.size(); i++) {
                mDb.fotosInsert(idIrregularidade, listFotos.get(i));
            }
    }

    mDb.close();

    reloadActivity();

}

// Reload MainActivity
public void reloadActivity() {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);

    NavDrawerFragment.mConfiguration = Config.configuration();
    NavDrawerFragment.mConfiguration =  NavDrawerFragment.mConfiguration.subList(0, 6);
    NavDrawerFragment.mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));

    startActivity(objIntent);
}

}
```

Comment: What is c? When do you call that row?

Comment: I forget to put a piece of code, c is an Object.

Comment: what is irregularidades ?

Comment: Please post your logcat here so that it helps in understanding the problem in more detail.

Comment: The problem is that listFotos is returning null , when the app goes on background, if I don't let it goes, it works fine!

Comment: @Ksenia I add the full code.

Comment: @PhanDinhThai is a hashmap

Answer (score 0):

Method `onCreateView`is invoked only once, when the fragment has to load UI on your screen. So you need to replace `saveData();` in another place.

Comment: That fragment is not displayed, I only use it as an item on the menu to save the data, so the OnCreateView will only be invoked when clicked on it. I'm not sure, if that is the problem, but I will look on it!